# problem in inheritence in java

Tags: java, swing, inheritance

I have a Frame class that I put one Jtree on it, now I developed a TreeSelectionListener for my tree. since my tree is in my Frame class how I can access to my tree ?

I want to know witch node pressed by user.
I create a stataic class from my frame class but I think this way is wrong please advice me.

```
public Frame1(){
    JTree jtree = new Jtree();
    public static Frame1 THIS;
     public Frame(){
     init();
     THIS = this;
     }
     public static getTHIS(){
         return THIS;
     }
}

public class jtreeSelectionListener implements TreeSelectionListener{

//here I need to access my jtree object, what should I do in this case?
// now I do like this . Frame1.getTHIS.jtree ...
}
```

Comment: May be by getting source of event in `valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e)` as `e.getSource()` and parse it in JTree

Comment: WhiteFAng's answer is spot on, though you should be careful when yielding that static keyword.  It does have it's use but most of the time is misused to circumvent limitations on a design by creating a global variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a constructor for `JTreeSelectionListener` that takes your `JTree`:

```
public class Frame1 extends JFrame {
    private JTree jtree = new JTree();

    public Frame1() {
        jtree.addTreeSelectionListener(new JTreeSelectionListener(jtree));
    }
}

public class JTreeSelectionListener implements TreeSelectionListener {
    private JTree jtree;

    public JTreeSelectionListener(JTree jtree) {
        this.jtree = jtree;
    }

    public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help & support, I dont know why I forgot to write my code like this :-? name of this site really is correct name ;)

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to combine the listener functionality with your frame class:

```
public class Frame1 extends JFrame implements JTreeSelectionListener {
    private JTree jtree = new JTree();

    public Frame1() {
        jtree.addTreeSelectionListener(this);
    }

    public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
        // can now access jtree directly ...
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 yeah if the classes are simple I tend to prefer this approach for listeners.